# array_udiff returns different results

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this piece of code to get a difference between two arrays of objects:

```
$diff = array_udiff($a, $b,
    function($obj_a, $obj_b) {
        return $obj_a->id - $obj_b->id;
    }
);
```

$a is

```
[
  {
    "id": "7",
    "attribute": "instagram"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "attribute": "snapchat"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "attribute": "facebook"
  }
]
```

$b is

```
[
  {
    "id": "7",
    "attribute": "instagram",
    "value": "somevalue"
  }
]
```

$diff should return array of objects

```
[
  {
    "id": "8",
    "attribute": "snapchat"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "attribute": "facebook"
  }
]
```

And it does, but only when $b is an empty array. The result is then correct (I get an array of objects, the $a, because $b is empty).

But when at least one object is present in the $b, the $diff is returning to me the following which I don't want.

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": "8",
    "attribute": "snapchat"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "9",
    "attribute": "facebook"
  }
}
```

How do I get an array of objects in the result instead of the above? And why there is a difference between the two results? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `$diff = array_values($diff);` before you `json_encode` so that the indexes will start at zero.

When you do the `array_udiff`, the keys of `$a` are preserved, so `$diff` has keys starting at 1 instead of 0. In order for `json_encode` to encode an array as a JSON array instead of a JSON object, the keys must be sequential and start at zero. `array_values` will reindex the array so that this condition will be met.

Just to be clear, even if other items were removed from the array instead of the first one, so that the indexes still started with zero, you would still need to reindex `$diff` because of the missing keys.